# How to use ncurses in Dart?

Tags: dart, ncurses

Is there such a possibility to use `ncurses` in Dart?

http://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/ncurses.html

Answer (score 4):

There is no direct support. You can create a binding using the native extension.
See https://www.dartlang.org/articles/native-extensions-for-standalone-dart-vm/ for more details.

Answer (score 1):

Now that the [ncurses package](https://pub.dev/packages/ncurses) exists, it seems you no longer have to create the binding yourself.

Comment: Too late. This is no longer relevant. The question was asked 8 years ago. Your answer is already useless.

Comment: For you, that may be true, and it doesn't even surprise me given those 8 years. However, your question can still be found by others, and I thought I could point them to the solution.

Comment: Have you tried it and that works?